# Go-MongoDriver decoding JSON array weirdly

Tags: mongodb, go, fibers

Heyho party people,

I've recently took up learning Go and started working on a small side project which includes a API written using the Go Fiber library.
All the necessery data is stored in MongoDB with the following schema

```json
{
    "ObjectId": {
        "name": "name",
        "url": "url",
        "dateAdded": "date",
        "data": [{
                "timestamp 1": "price 1"
            },
            {
                "timestamp 2": "price 2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The item type looks like this:

```golang
type Item struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    Name      string             `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    URL       string             `json:"url" bson:"url"`
    DateAdded string             `json:"dateAdded" bson:"dateAdded"`
    Data      []interface{}      `json:"data" bson:"data"`
}
```

Whenever I query a stored item with

```golang
err = collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter).Decode(&item)
```

each map inside of the data-array is wrapped in another array =>

```json
{ test url 2021-04-16 [[{2021-04-16 99.99}] [{2021-04-17 109.99}]] }

instead of

{ test url 2021-04-16 [{2021-04-16 99.99}, {2021-04-17 109.99}] }
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The example json is not valid json, why is that? typo? or is that not supposed to be json but instead something that's only json-like?

Comment: Can you share the definition of the `item`'s type?

Comment: My bad, I fixed the JSON (which I copied incorrectly into the question) and added the item's type

Comment: The schema and the retrieved data sure look inconsistent. However the retrieved data is data that *you* have stored there, I presume, so it seems to me that the problem is going to be not with what you're retrieving but with what you're storing. *How* certain are you that the items you are storing are consistent with the schema? 100%? Can you show how you're doing the storing? And what the data looks prior to being stored?

Comment: I am somewhat sure that this schema is consistent lol. I am quite certain that there are a lot of possibilities to improve this JSON schema but the one I posted above was simply an idea I had which, to me, made sense.

However, since I am practically a complete Go and MongoDB noob I was unsure whether this problem is caused by MongoDB, Go or the Go-Mongo-driver, which is why I figured I'd ask here.

Comment: "somewhat sure" is not sure enough when it comes to programming.

Comment: But nobody can help you if you provide information that you are only "somewhat sure" is true. How are we supposed to help if we don't know that what you're claiming is true is actually true, and does actually represent the real state of the program.

Comment: You need to first establish that the mongo database does indeed store the `data` part of your json in a one dimensional array, i.e. `"data": [{...}]` and not in a two-dimensional array, i.e. `"data": [[{ ... }]]`. Once you are 100% sure that of what the structure inside the db is, and if you still see that when retrieved using Go the resulting structure is inconsistent with the db, then you are more than welcome to ask a question on SO.

Comment: Just to clarify, as I feel that there might be a bit of misunderstanding here, your question in itself is not bad. It's an ok question for SO. What I was asking in my previous comment is **how certain are you** that the data in mongo db is stored as `"data": [{ ... }]` and not as `"data": [[{ ... }]]`? Because if, in Go, you're getting back `[[{2021-04-16 99.99}] [{2021-04-17 109.99}]]` then it is much more likely that the data in mongo is `"data": [[{ ... }]]` and not `"data": [{ ... }]` *and* if that's actually the case then your question stops being an ok question. Am I making sense?

Comment: My data in MongoDB is stored as ```data: [{ key: val }, {key: val}]```, every query I perform using the mongo-shell confirms that.
However, when queried using Go and the respective driver for MongoDB, the result set I receive looks like ```data: [[{key: val}], [{key: val}]]```.
So basically each entry in the array gets wrapped into another array and I have no clue why.
I wanted to clarify whether this is a problem of the driver itself (or even Go) or my query, because in MongoDB, there is no problem with the schema whatsoever.

Comment: Ok, I see, that does seem odd. What is the result if you change the Go field from `Data []interface{}` to `Data interface{}`?

Comment: Stays the same.

Comment: For sure this is not a Go problem, and probably also not a driver "problem" but rather a conscious decision on how to unmarshal the data into an unknown type. When you print the type of the data field, what do you get? `fmt.Printf("%T\n", item.Data)` (add `[0]` if you changed it back to `[]interface{}`)

Comment: Also try changing the field's type to one of the types predefined by the driver and its related packages. i.e. What happens if you change the field to `Data bson.A`? And also take a look at the bson's docs, they lay out the rules for decoding the bson data into Go, so the behaviour you're experiencing is likely to be mentioned there: https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#pkg-overview and if it's not try some of the related packages. Finally, if this is big problem, try the project's github issues, first search if someone else has the same problem, if not, open a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found a way to fix this behaviour for my use case.

As mentioned above, the MongoDB-driver for Go wraps each entry of an array into another respective array, which leads to a nested array.

After trying around for some time I found out, that inserting the document into your collection like the following example,

```js
db.collection.insertOne({ name: "Name", url: "URL", dateAdded: "2021-04-25", data: { "2021-04-25": 9.99, "2021-04-26": 19.99 } })
```

then the result of a query performed in your program looks like this:

```js
{ ObjectID("60858245f8805dc57a716500") Name URL 2021-04-25 [{ 2021-04-25 9.99 } { 2021-04-26 19.99 }] }
```

This means, that the JSON-schema should look like this

```json
{
    "ObjectId": {
        "name": "name",
        "url": "url",
        "dateAdded": "date",
        "data": {
            "2021-04-25": 9.99,
            "2021-04-26": 19.99
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly, I was not able to find out what is actually causing this odd behaviour, but I hope this helps anybody encountering this (or a similar) problem.

## EDIT

Changing the type of the `Data`-field to `[]bson.M`, as [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) said in the comments below, fixed it.

```golang
type Item struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    Name      string             `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    URL       string             `json:"url" bson:"url"`
    DateAdded string             `json:"dateAdded" bson:"dateAdded"`
    Data      []bson.M           `json:"data" bson:"data"`
}
```

This way the original JSON-schema does not have to be adapted to the workaround.

```json
{
    "ObjectId":{
        "name":"name",
        "url":"url",
        "dateAdded":"date",
        "data": [
            {
                "2021-04-25": 9.99
            },
            {
                "2021-04-26": 19.99
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you might be able to get the desired result by changing the field's type to `[]bson.M` (a slice of maps) or to `bson.D` (a slice of single key-value pairs, by single I mean *one* kv pair per element in slice). What happens when you use `[]interface{}`, I think, is that bson unmarshals the individual `interface{}` elements of the slice by default to `bson.D` and then populates the slice with them. At least that's what I gather from: *"BSON documents unmarshalled into an interface{} field will be unmarshalled as a D."* (which is stated in the docs I linked in one of my comments above).

Comment: I changed the type of the ```Data```-field to ```primitive.D``` (printed the type of the data field to the terminal). Neither of your suggestions works as both result in an error.

Comment: I've just tried `[]bson.M` and in addition to that also `[]map[string]interface{}` and both work they way you seem to desire, the output of fmt.Print looks like `[map[2021-04-25:9.99] map[2021-04-26:19.99]]` which is equivalent to `[{"2021-04-25": 9.99}, {"2021-04-26": 19.99}]`.

Comment: https://imgur.com/9mSzG7y -- it is what you were looking for isn't it?

Comment: It is, but when I try it with either ```[]bson.M``` or ```[]map[string]interface{}```, I receive the following error, as soon as the query is executed:

```error decoding key data: cannot decode document into []primitive.M
exit status 1```
```error decoding key data: cannot decode document into []map[string]interface {}
exit status 1```

Comment: That's only after you've changed the schema in the db from `"data":[{...}]` to `"data":{...}`. Try retrieving a record with your original schema into `[]map[string]interface{}` or `[]bson.M` to make it work. I get the same error as you when I try to retrieve a record with `"data":{...}` and I get the result in the linked image when I try to retrieve a record with `"data":[{...}]`.

Comment: OK. Works like a charm now. I kinda feel dumb now. Thanks a lot! Really appreciate your patience, stamina and help in general!

Comment: no problem, I'm glad the issue got resolved

Comment: Can I mark your comment as an answer to my question? I am not that experienced when it comes to SO.

Comment: Nope that's not possible, but don't worry about it. Just update your answer with the new solution.